# How do I append a setting to the defaults in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I believe this is a general question about JSON and how VS-code handles settings, but I will give a specific example below that regards the LaTeXWorkshop extension.

I am used to overwriting settings in settings.json by adding lines such as `"option": value"`.

But what if `"option"` expects a list, and I just want to append a new element to the defaults, without removing the defaults. How do I do that?

---

**Specific Example using LaTeXWorkshop**
The default for the `latex-workshop-latex-recipe` option is given by this (see [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-recipes)):

```
[
  {
    "name": "latexmk ",
    "tools": [
      "latexmk"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex`×2",
    "tools": [
      "pdflatex",
      "bibtex",
      "pdflatex",
      "pdflatex"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to add the following item to this list *without removing the two defaults*:

```
{
    "names": ".Rnw: knitr -> latexmk",
    "tools": [
        "knitr",
        "latexmk"
    ]
}
```

If I add this to my settings, the default recipes seem to be deleted:

```
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes" : [{
        "names": ".Rnw: knitr -> latexmk",
        "tools": [
            "knitr",
            "latexmk"
        ]
    }],
```

How do I append instead of replacing?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that, and I haven't seen anything like it, so I don't think it's possible.  But I'm only commenting since I haven't dug into the source to prove it.

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98792